# bootstrap fluid container boxes for different screen sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fullscreen, fluid-layout

i am trying to implement a design with fluid-container in bootstrap 3.

no matter how i try, the boxes position is different when tested on various screens.

The design is suppose to look like this

[HomePage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o24BY.jpg)

And what i have implemented is here

```
<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Marketing Icons Section -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 c1">
             <img src="images/slider.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 c2">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 c3">
                    <img src="images/user.png" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 c4">
                <h1>BOX1</h1>

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 c5">

                <h1>BOX2</h1>
                </div>
             </div>

             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 c6">
                <h1>BOX3</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 c7">
                <h1>BOX4</h1>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row bottom_bg">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
     4+ XXXXXXX
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
     444+ XXXXXXX
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
     6664+ XXXXXXX
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
     89894+ XXXXXXX
    </div>
    </div>
```

Sample:
http://riyalinew.jeddahloyalty.com/html/

- Should i be using img-responsive class on the slider box ?
- Should i be adding min-height to the left side 4 boxes ?
- When the brower window is resized, left boxes are coming on top of right slider box.

  - On a big screen the right boxes and left boxes show a wide white area in between .

Is it possible to implement this design with fluid-container ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add col-md-x to your div.col-lg-x class name. col-lg-x has been designed for large screens and set a different scale value to your layout.

Comment: the effect is same, the issue is that the boxes on left side should be always equal to the big banner box on right side .

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Okay editing in chrome tool,max i could do this. I did not use a fixed height.This can be solves using flexbox. If your boxes had content. I could produce same result. I still cudnt figure out how to add upper profile link while keeping boxes same height.

```
  <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Marketing Icons Section -->
        <div class="row" style="
    display: -webkit-flex;  
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
">


         <div class="col-lg-8 c1" style="flex: 2;">
                 <img src="images/slider.png" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 c2" style="
    padding: 0px;
    /* margin: 0px; */
    flex: 1;
    background: rgba(0, 173, 166, 0.41);">
<div class="c1 row" style="height: 50vh;">//box 1,23,4 row here
```

Comment: what happens when you resize the browser or see it in a bigger screen ..

Comment: It will work fine on larger screens but for smaller devices you need to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

Use col-xs to use the same form even in small screen.

Comment: what do you think about the slider box on right side. how i will be able to keep slider box and left side boxes in the same finishing line. ( on different monitor screens )

Comment: Set the image to responsive. Add the following css .c1 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}